# How to avoid that when calling a MatDialog inside another MatDialog the first MatDialog is closed in Angular 5?

Tags: angular, angular-material

I have a MatDialog from which I want to open another (to confirm an operation). The problem is that when the second MatDialog is opened the first one is closed, which is not a desired effect.

I have seen that in previous versions the 'multiple' property existed, but now it is not in https://material.angular.io/components/dialog/api

Does anyone know how it could be done? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My apologies. It took a long time without finding a solution, but I kept looking and I found the cause of the problem.

It was silly. I mention it in case someone happens: in the template of the first MatDialog had placed everything in a form. Then the button that opened the second MatDialog submit the form, which caused the closure of the first MatDialog.

I have already changed it and it works perfectly.